# Enabling CloudWatch Integration for EC2Config version 4.2.1442

Tags: amazon-web-services, monitoring, amazon-cloudwatch

I have tried sending custom metrics to Cloud Watch.

For Ec2Config version till 4.1, I had to enable the cloud watch logs integration. It looked like the following :

[image]

Now, I am trying to do it for the instances whose Ec2Config service version is 4.2.1442, but the **Cloud Watch Integration Checkbox** is **not visible**. Infact, the CloudWatch Logs section is not being shown. Because of this, I am unable to send custom metrics to CLoudWatch.

How do I enable CloudWatch Logs integration now? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using an updated version of EC2Config (4.2.x), and this is the reason why I am unable to find the CloudWatch Logs Integration checkbox.

According to AWS Documentation :

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/send_logs_to_cwl.html

***Step 2*** clearly notes the following :

```
NOTE :

If you don't see the Enable CloudWatch Logs integration option, then you are using an updated version of the EC2Config service that no longer supports enabling CloudWatch integration. You must use Systems Manager Run Command to enable CloudWatch integration.
```

As suggested, I followed the following link :

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/remote-commands-cloudwatch.html

By following that, I was able to solve it. My instance had no IAM Role attached, so I attached it using the AWS CLI. Then, I ran the Run Command from the AWS EC2 console which automatically pushed custom performance counters to CloudWatch.